# SVD when only off-diagonal terms are known

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a real matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that:

- $A$ is symmetric
- All the off-diagonal terms are known and positive
- Has rank $k<n$

Unfortunately I don't know the values of the diagonal terms $A_{i,i}$, but I know that they are positive; what can be said in this case about SVD decomposition? Is there a way to calculate an approximate SVD having diagonal terms of the matrix to be decomposed undetermined?

Comment: In which context does this arise? Any possibility of building some statistical or probability model for the missing diagonal?

Comment: If you could give more details of your real problem, I'm sure we can help!

Comment: If you can easily estimate off-diagonals, can you change basis and use this to estimate the diagonal? The opposite (polarization identities) is a well-known trick.

Comment: This can be solved as an approximate optimization problem, without truly doing a true SVD.

Comment: @Suvrit and Federico, do you have a reference for your comments? I would be great!

Comment: @Kjetil, unfortunately I don't have many other details, I am just surfing the literature about mixture models, and seems that nobody cares about the absence of diagonal terms, so from this my question..

Comment: Can you at least give reference to some of the papers you are surfing?

Comment: This of course can't work in this generality, because the off-diagonal terms could be almost zero and everything is dominated by the unknown diagonal.

Comment: The question at this point is not well-posed but here are a few "search directions" which lead to potential approaches for solving your problem. One key term you are looking for is "missing values".  "missing value svd" on google throws up many papers and even matlab code. The only constraint you have stated is that the matrix is low rank. This suggests that one of the billion different "low rank matrix completion" approaches could work. Another clue is that the matrix has only positive elements. Maybe the diagonals should also be positive? That would suggest "low rank nmf matrix completion".